# How to limit drag & drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

My code is like this :

HTML :

```
<form action="example3_action.php" name="example3" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id='serialize_output' name="serialize_output">
    <div class='span4'>
        box 1 (Customer)
        <ol class='nested_with_switch test1 vertical'>
            <li data-id="1" data-name='Valentino Rossi'>Valentino Rossi</li>
            <li data-id="2" data-name='David Beckham'>David Beckham</li>
            <li data-id="3" data-name='Eden Hazard'>Eden Hazard</li>
            <li data-id="4" data-name='Lionel Messi'>Lionel Messi</li>
            <li data-id="5" data-name='Christiano Ronaldo'>Christiano Ronaldo</li>
            <li data-id="6" data-name='Frank Lampard'>Frank Lampard</li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class='span4'>
        box 2 (Room Type)
        <ol class='nested_with_switch test2 vertical'>
            <li data-id="1" data-name='Single Room' class='highlight'>Single Room<ol></ol></li>
            <li data-id="2" data-name='Double Room' class='highlight'>Double Room<ol></ol></li>
            <li data-id="3" data-name='Family Room' class='highlight'>Family Room<ol></ol></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <!--<button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>-->
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
var oldContainer;
    var group = $("ol.nested_with_switch").sortable({
      group: 'nested',
      afterMove: function (placeholder, container) {
        if(oldContainer != container){
          if(oldContainer)
            oldContainer.el.removeClass("active");
          container.el.addClass("active");

          oldContainer = container;
        }
      },
      onDrop: function ($item, container, _super) {

      var data = group.sortable("serialize").get();

      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ');
      console.log(jsonString);
      $('#serialize_output').val(jsonString);

        container.el.removeClass("active");
        _super($item, container);
      }
    });
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/wyyzz9bt/3/

I want limit drag & drop like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrYwC.jpg

I try like this :

```
$("ol.test2").sortable({
        group:  'nested',
        drop: false,
        drag: false,
    });
    $("ol.test2>li>ol").sortable({
        group:  'nested',
        drop: true,

    });
```

But it's not working

Any suggestion to solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/wyyzz9bt/5/

I had just moved the `nested_with_switch` class to the nested `<ol>`

Comment: I want to get the data json from room type (box 2) as well. I check on the console, it's just getting the data json from the customer (box 1).

Comment: What is the expected outcome? From what I see in the console there are four arrays, first for box 1 and the next 3 arrays for box 2

Comment: I wanted room type is also displayed in the form json like this : http://imgur.com/OBUpcnf. Whether it can be like that?

Comment: Of course that is up to you to massage the data, not the plugin itself

Comment: I still difficult to show like it. Whether it can not? I want to take the data room type.

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121287/how-to-use-redis-in-codeigniter